# Elastic tabstops in LaTeX

Tags: code, tabbing

I was wondering if it's possible to implement elastic tabstops for code in TeX or LaTeX?

##### Summary of elastic tabstops

See page https://nickgravgaard.com/elastic-tabstops/ for more information.

[image: Elastic tabstops illustration, since they are a visual aid, I don't know how to best describe this image for people using screen readers.]

In the above image, for the function definition there is a tab before the first argument, and on the next line, there is a tab before the second argument. Elastic tabstops then makes those two arguments line up.

Then the next line has no tabs in it, this resets the position of the first tabstop, so in the following lines the first tabstop is at four spaces in (or some other metric, e.g. four em spaces).

The next three lines illustrate that the tabstop isn't set to the position of the first line containing that tabstop, but to the rightmost tabstop of that group.

##### Implementation ideas

My first implementation idea was to just use LaTeX tabbing environment, like so:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
int someDemoCode(\quad\= int start,                    \\
                      \> int length)                   \\
\{                                                     \\
\quad\= x()                \quad\= /* try making    */ \\
     \> print("hello!")         \> /* this comment  */ \\
     \> doSomethingComplicated()\> /* a bit longer  */ \\
     \> for (i in range(start, length))                \\
     \> \{                                             \\
     \> \quad\= if (isValid(i))                        \\
     \>      \> \{                                     \\
     \>      \> \quad\= count++                        \\
     \>      \> \}                                     \\
     \> \}                                             \\
     \> return count                                   \\
\}                                                     \\
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

and this gets me most of the way, except in the places where the first line containing that tabstop isn't the longest. I could manually find out the longest line, and insert  a `\kill` line, e.g.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
int someDemoCode(\quad\= int start,                         \\
                      \> int length)                        \\
\{                                                          \\
\quad\= doSomethingComplicated()\quad\= /* a bit longer  */ \kill
     \> x()                          \> /* try making    */ \\
     \> print("hello!")              \> /* this comment  */ \\
     \> doSomethingComplicated()     \> /* a bit longer  */ \\
     \> for (i in range(start, length))                     \\
     \> \{                                                  \\
     \> \quad\= if (isValid(i))                             \\
     \>      \> \{                                          \\
     \>      \> \quad\= count++                             \\
     \>      \> \}                                          \\
     \> \}                                                  \\
     \> return count                                        \\
\}                                                          \\
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

But this would be tedious and also wouldn't work with noweb.

##### Notes

I should point out that I am okay with a small awk program that does some translation of the code, I'm using noweb, and that supports filters that could e.g. insert the `\>`/`\=`. The question here is more about making `tabbing` behave more like `table` in that it's the longest column that's used, not the first. Also, I imagine it's simpler to have something that doesn't also incorporate the listings environment, I'm also happy with that.

Comment: As you said, this IS how a tabular (using l columns) functions.  If you want to go old school, look up \halign.

Comment: Yeah, I think the difficulty I have with tables, is that what I want, is a nested table, for each column nesting to the right. This is because I don't want to lose the columns/tabstops for e.g. columns 1 and 2, when column 3 ends or restarts. I don't think tables support this?

Comment: You can nest tabulars of one or two columns each, although the resulting lines won't quite line up.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Nesting tabulars has very high markup overhead. It is not suitable for not very short code listings. Also, tabular doesn't work with highlighting across tabstops. If I try to use `\textbf` on something containing a column separator, it will not compile.

Comment: Give the parser a break: `\textbf{...} & \textbf{...}`  As for code listing, the listings package can create inline code listtings, and alignment can usually be achieved by adding struts.